# "even if original gets changes" or "even if original changes"

Tags: grammar

Which would be the grammatically  correct form of this sentence?

> This object will not change his state anymore, even if original gets changes.

or

> This object will not change his state anymore, even if original changes.

Is either of these the correct way to say it? Or would a native speaker of English put it another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions need just a little work on the *article* and *pronoun*:

- "change his state" should be "change **its** state" (object is not male/female)
- "if original" should be "if **the** original

Now there is the question of "gets changes" vs "change".

"changes" is okay, it could mean the object changes on it own, or by something else acting on it.

"gets changes" is not idiomatic.

To say that something or someone changes the original intentionally, you might say

" gets change**d** [by ...]

To say that something (unmentioned) changes the original, try

- "is  changed"

As for "anymore", use that word **only if you know the object has already changed state at least once**, because "anymore" implies *ceasing to change*.  if you mean only that it will not change after some point in time or stage in a process (whether or not it has changed before then), say:

"...will not change after that {time/phase}...

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
This object will not change its state anymore, even if the original changes.
```

or:

```
This object will not change its state anymore, even if the original gets changed.
```

Not the article `the` before original and the `-ed` verb form of `changed`.

Correct if I'm wrong, but english is not my mother language and I feel the changes above are needed.

Let me know if I understood what you tried to say in the sentences.

Comment: The pronoun for an object is *Its* not *his*.

Comment: @TimLymington You're right.. I totally missed that, thank you